# streamR, filterStream ends instantly

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to R and apologize in advance if this is a very simple issue. I want to make use of the package streamR, however I receive the following output when I execute the filterStream function:

*Capturing tweets...
Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 0 seconds with up to 1 tweets downloaded.*

I am wondering if I am missing a step during authentication. I am able to successfully use the twitteR package and obtain tweets through the searchTwitter function. Is there something more that I need in order to gain access to the streaming api?

```
library("ROAuth")
library("twitteR")
library("streamR")
library("RCurl")
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey="xxxxxyyyyyzzzzzz",
                     consumerSecret="xxxxxxyyyyyzzzzzzz111111222222"',
                     requestURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
                     accessURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
                     authURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')

cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl") )

save(cred, file="twitter authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)

scoring<- searchTwitter("Landon Donovan", n=100, cainfo="cacert.pem")

filterStream( file.name="tweets_rstats.json",track="Landon Donovan", tweets=10, oauth=cred)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your credentials look fine. There are a few possible answers I've encountered while working within R:

1. If you are trying to run this on more than one computer at a time (or someone else is using your API keys), it won't work because you are only allowed one connection per API Key. The same goes for attempting to run it in two different projects.
2. It's possible that the internet connection won't allow access to the API to do the scraping. On certain days or in certain locations, my code won't run even after establishing connection. I'm not sure if this has to do with certain controls on the connection or what the deal is, but one day it'll run on client sites and others it won't.

**3. It seems as though if you run a pull and then run another one immediately after, then the 0 tweets/1 second message appears. I don't think you're abusing the rate limit, but there may be a wait period in order to stream again.**

4 . A final suggestion would be to make sure you have "Read, Write, and Access Direct Messages" allowed in your Application Preferences. This may not make the difference, but then you aren't limiting any connections.

Other than these, there aren't any "quick fixes" I've encountered, for me it's usually just waiting around, so when I run a pull I make sure to capture a large number of tweets or capture for a few hours at a time.

Comment: Thank you Sam for your reply. It looks like it might be #2 from your list. I haven't shared my API key, am not near the rate limit and have selected "Read, Write, and Access Direct Messages." When I have spare time, I am working at it and will hopefully find a solution to share.

Comment: I am having the same problem, any updates? @JuanBecks